# Disabling javadoc in ant build

Tags: java, maven, ant

How do we disable javadocs in ant projects? Like in maven we use something like this:

`-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`

Comment: First without the Ant files it's hard to guess apart from that there should be conditions defined (which I have my doubts about)... Really using Ant based builds?

Comment: @khmarbaise - I am working on Apache Pig project which uses Ant

Comment: Does that help ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your solution shared.

Comment: Your answer does not help here which project you are working on... apart from that if you are working on an apache project I recommend to ask on the developer list of the project...

Comment: Um… remove the `<javadoc>` task from the build file?  Or execute an Ant task which doesn’t depend on any task that executes `<javadoc>`?  Ant is not a ‘do everything automatically for you’ tool.  Ant does what you ask it to do, and no more.